# Best way to convert INT to BIT

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have column type of INT, I want to select 1 if it contains 1 and 0 otherwise. I know only way to do it using CASE:

```
CASE WHEN val=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0
```

What other approaches there is to achieve the same result?

Comment: `DECLARE @r VARCHAR(10)='1'
 SELECT CAST(@r AS BIT)`

Comment: @RoyiNamir: **INT** but string ;)

Comment: @danihp will work also if val is int :-)

Comment: @RoyiNamir ... just to catch OP question.

Comment: You can try SELECT CAST(val AS bit)

Comment: @Snorre unfortunately no. INT(2) also caster to BIT(1)

Comment: @RoyiNamir nice, but not applicable inside select to multiple rows.

Comment: @AlexG.P. What do you mean ? pls supply sample

Comment: You are not trying to convert `INT` to `BIT`. Every `INT` can be converted to `BIT` - `SELECT TRY_CONVERT(BIT,2147483647)`. If the integer is `0` then the conversion will return `0`, otherwise `1`.

Answer (score 53):

SQL SERVER 2012:

```
SELECT CAST(IIF ( field = 1, 1, 0 ) AS BIT) FROM table
```

Otherwise:

```
SELECT CAST(CASE field WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS BIT) From table
```

Comment: I believe best practice is to check if `field` = 0 instead

Comment: @Greg That wouldn't solve the OP's problem, which is specifically about testing for the value 1.

Answer (score 20):

All you have to do is cast/convert the `int` to a `bit`.

```
DECLARE
     @val INT = 42;
    ,@bitVal BIT;

SET @bitVal = CAST(@val AS BIT); -- equals 1
```

Any non-zero number will be converted to true.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191530(v=sql.105).aspx#_bit

Comment: The OP's question says "select 1 if it contains 1 and 0 otherwise".  So this would convert any value other than 0 or 1 to the wrong value.

Comment: You are correct. :) I read the title and apparently just skimmed the question.

Answer (score 4):

To convert is simple, as long as it is 1 or 0 you can just assign it, no need to cast anything

you do the same when you declare a variable right?

```
@declare @myBit bit =1;
```

however when you want to do something more useful with the integer like bitmap comparison things get more interesting. you can compare two integers and return a bit based on the way the defined.
Let me try and visualise

```
    00000001=1
    00000010=2
    00000011=3
==============
    FFFFFFTT
```

so if you have a 1 the value becomes True,

Actually it is a bitmap comparison with 2 values is like mapping a raster, you can have several or even group them using 0+1 at a byte level.

Above you can see that 1 "is in" 3 as well as that 2 "is in" 3

look at the TSQL unit test example below

```
declare @notSet     int =0
      , @CanView    int =1 
      , @CanEdit    int =2 
      , @CanSubmit  int =4 
      , @CanApprove int =8
      , @CanDelete  int =16; 

declare @contributor int = @CanView | @CanEdit | @CanSubmit     --> Can't delete
       , @moderator  int = @CanView | @CanEdit | @CanDelete     --> not allowed to sumbit
       , @admin      int = @CanView | @CanEdit | @CanSubmit | @CanApprove | @CanDelete;--> can do all

SELECT TEST='A admin can Submit'            , RESULT= iif(@admin     & @CanSubmit = @CanSubmit,'TRUE','FALSE')
UNION ALL
SELECT TEST='A Moderator may not Submit'    , RESULT= iif(@moderator & @CanSubmit = @CanSubmit,'FALSE','TRUE')
UNION ALL
SELECT TEST='A Contributer may not delete'  , RESULT= iif(@contributor & @CanDelete = @CanDelete,'FALSE','TRUE')
UNION ALL
SELECT TEST='A Moderator may delete'        , RESULT= iif(@moderator & @CanDelete = @CanDelete,'TRUE','FALSE')
```

You can combine the values together using the bit operator | 
like this 1|2 = 3, and 1|1 =1, do not mix up "|" with  a "+" here as it will not always work well ;-)

An example, the bug would be  @CanView  + @CanView would be **@CanEdit**,

when you expect @CanView | @canView will still be  @canView

Try it in SQL

```
SELECT (1|1), (1+1)
```

Below some C#, Hope it helps those that like to save and work with enums in code and database.

Say you have an Enum and a class like this:
    [Flags]
    public enum Rights
    {
        notSet  =0
      , CanView =1 
      , CanEdit =2 
      , CanSubmit =4 
      , CanApprove =8
      , CanDelete =16
    }

```
public class User
{
  public Rights Permission {get;set}
}

...
// user can change his own posts
var user = new User();
user.Permission = Rights.CanView | Rights.CanEdit | Rights.CanDelete ;
```

You can now store the permission in the database and read the value using one of the below methods where you compare one or compare several

```
var result = user.Permission & Rights.CanView  == Rights.CanView;
var canChange = ((user.Permission & (Rights.CanView  | Rights.CanEdit | Rights.CanDelete)) != 0);
```

So, Round Tripped to the database and back, hope you have what you are looking for

Happy coding,

Walter

Comment: This would convert any value other than 0 or 1 to 1, rather than 0 as the OP is asking for.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one more solution. Without `case` or `iif`:

```
select ~cast(sign(abs(@i - 1)) as bit)
```

But it doesn't work if @i = -2147483648. You should then convert it to `bigint`.

Comment: all you need is this: SELECT~cast(val-1as bit)